# No web processes running Error - Deploying Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am using the tutorial to deploy Django. [http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django] After I do a git push heroku master, there are no web processes.

```
Process  State  Command  
-------  -----  -------
```

On the log it looks like the following.

```
2012-04-13T03:48:45+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-04-13T03:49:32+00:00 heroku[api]: Config add PYTHONUNBUFFERED, PYTHONPATH, PATH,     
LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LANG, PYTHONHOME, LIBRARY_PATH, PYTHONHASHSEED by zach@gmail.com
2012-04-13T03:49:32+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by zach@gmail.com
2012-04-13T03:49:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by zach@gmail.com
2012-04-13T03:49:34+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d1263ef by zach@gmail.com
2012-04-13T03:49:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to down
2012-04-13T03:49:35+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-04-13T03:50:19+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET    
growing-winter-4952.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any ideas? I was able to get this to work with another app.  Thank you.

Also when I do a heroku scale web=1                 I get this

```
Scaling web processes...  !    Record not found.
```

Comment: What happens when you [run locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#running_a_worker) using `foreman start`? Can you post the output?

Comment: I am getting a ERROR: Procfile does not exist  message. I have a Procfile on the same level as my requirements. On my Procfile it says:web: python project/manage.py runserver "0.0.0.0:$PORT"

Comment: I now get 10:53:26 web.1     | started with pid 12157
10:53:29 web.1     | Error: ""0.0.0.0:5000"" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.
10:53:29 web.1     | process terminated
10:53:29 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? If you're using Django 1.4, you'll notice the path to your `manage.py` is not `project/manage.py`, but rather it is on the same level as your Procfile. I was able to introduce a similar error message(`not a valid port number or address:port pair`) by enclosing the IP/port address in quotes--it should not be in quotes, it should look something [like this](https://gist.github.com/2378353).

Comment: I am using Django 1.3.1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is most likely the result of scaling your web processes down to zero through the client.

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=0
```

Use the `heroku ps` command to determine the state of your web processes., and you should take a look at the [Error Codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) to understand the Heroku functionality.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem. At first, when I ran `heroku scale web=1`, I got the same 'Record not found' error as you. But I waited a few minutes and ran it again, and it worked.

If your build fails on the first push for some reason, then heroku doesn't automatically give you a web process, and the 'Record not found' error might've cropped up because something was off with the build at that point.