# build and deployment success but no web process running on Heroku on Spark (Java Framework)

Tags: java, heroku, spark-java

I'm getting a no web process error even though the project was built and deployed successfully. Here's my Procfile to specify how to run my java spark app.

```
 java -jar target/simplenlg-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I've also used foreman start to check to see if it's running and yes it's working.

Here's my code that'll determine the port

```
static int getHerokuAssignedPort() {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(); 
    if (processBuilder.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
        return Integer.parseInt(processBuilder.environment().get("PORT"));
    }
    return 4567;
}
```

I've followed this tutorial but it's still not working for me...

> https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/08/24/spark-heroku.html
>   https://gist.github.com/jesperfj/1222739
>   https://gist.github.com/Fitzsimmons/2490382

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what happened but I followed this [No web processes running Error - Deploying Django on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142284/no-web-processes-running-error-deploying-django-on-heroku).

```
heroku scale web=1
```

Then do another mvn heroku:deploy and now it works.