# i created a django software its running on localhost,but not working on heroku its log is showing this

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku, hosting

I am getting following error in the log file. Project Directory Tree, settings.py and Procfile are added below. How can I solve it.

All project file are on [ShubhamSjain2000/stockware](https://github.com/ShubhamSjain2000/stockware)

Log Error:

```
2020-11-28T07:50:10.254987+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user shubham1900jain@gmail.com
2020-11-28T07:50:10.531132+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d9583d0a by user shubham1900jain@gmail.com
2020-11-28T07:50:10.531132+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user shubham1900jain@gmail.com
2020-11-28T07:50:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-28T07:50:35.159601+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=stockware.herokuapp.com request_id=0b1c2b67-1ac9-4247-8f90-fb928da59cd6 fwd="182.70.189.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-28T07:50:36.170169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stockware.herokuapp.com request_id=af302f4c-e5cc-405e-ba97-30a07516c784 fwd="182.70.189.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-29T04:12:18.801989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=stockware.herokuapp.com request_id=e9644275-2548-4405-8dab-7f58291c79ec fwd="182.70.190.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-29T04:12:23.337106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stockware.herokuapp.com request_id=54638bf1-67b2-4982-8e2c-365826a046f2 fwd="182.70.190.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-29T04:19:50.571393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=stockware.herokuapp.com request_id=ac335c25-ed5e-4faa-909d-9208375721f7 fwd="182.70.190.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-29T04:19:51.945843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stockware.herokuapp.com request_id=ba9f09fb-8aff-4096-af16-cb673534520e fwd="182.70.190.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Project Directory Tree**

```
- accounts/
   - admin.py
   - apps.py
   - models.py
   - tests.py
   - urls.py
   - views.py
- assets/
- price/
   - admin.py
   - apps.py
   - models.py
   - tests.py
   - urls.py
   - views.py
- static/
   - contact.html
   - home.html
   - money.jpg
   - navbar.html
   - profile.html
   - scripts.html
- stock/
   - asgi.py
   - settings.py
   - urls.py
   - wsgi.py
- templates/
   - app.html
   - contact.html
   - globalindices.html
   - holdings.html
   - index.html
   - login.html
   - profile.html
   - register.html
   - research.html
   - scripts.html
- Procfile
- db.sqlite3
- manage.py
- requirements.txt
- stock.sqlite3
```

Below is the settings file.

**stock/settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'price.apps.PriceConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stock.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stock.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'stock.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

Below is my Procfile.

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn STOCK.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No web processes running Error - Deploying Django on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142284/no-web-processes-running-error-deploying-django-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you aren't getting more helpful error messages. One issue is that you are pointing Gunicorn at a module called `STOCK.wsgi`, but your module is actually called `stock.wsgi`.

Change your `Procfile` accordingly:

```
web: gunicorn stock.wsgi --log-file -
```