# how solve Error when run django app on server of heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

i create django app and now i run it on heroku app my procfile and other thing are as follow. but when i build it on heroku then it succesfully uploaded but not run on website.
this app is run in localhost is good but not at online

hear is procfile
`web: waitress-server --port=$PORT todoapp.wsgi:application`

hear is last logs

````
2022-01-24T07:20:24.200304+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5e0ae6c8 by user zeelmehta.zm31@gmail.com
2022-01-24T07:20:24.200304+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user zeelmehta.zm31@gmail.com
2022-01-24T07:20:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-24T07:20:40.938065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=todoapp-zeel.herokuapp.com request_id=81d8bb3e-5f6c-4f37-8be0-90508cebef10 fwd="157.32.119.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-24T07:20:41.630709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=todoapp-zeel.herokuapp.com request_id=87aff06b-aff3-4846-9abc-95b1db51d632 fwd="157.32.119.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-24T07:20:55.134817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=todoapp-zeel.herokuapp.com request_id=9a920057-d443-4404-badd-493951c0c196 fwd="157.32.119.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-24T07:20:55.760932+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=todoapp-zeel.herokuapp.com request_id=0f0b6bfc-2181-4eb0-b0af-8e444058b163 fwd="157.32.119.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https```

please help me to solve this error
````

Comment: if anyone want to get more file ask me i will share all files

Comment: did you followed heroku documents? it said to use gunicorn to run the procfile, what is waitress-server anyway? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No web processes running Error - Deploying Django on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142284/no-web-processes-running-error-deploying-django-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

web: waitress-**serve** --port=$PORT todoapp.wsgi:application

change server to serve